Single Log Out (SLO) error when logging user out of salesforce community
I have single sign on configured where Salesforce is the SP, as shown below in screenshot and we need to use single log out (SLO) to log the community user out of salesforce and IDP as well.

However, we get an error when we try to log the user out of community using the following URL:
/${sitePrefix}vforcesite/secur/logout.jsp

Is there anything I am missing?
Or does this above error come up due to the IDP?

The Identity Provider Single Logout URL was incorrect and had to be updated.
